# paragraph2vec with more then 1000 words

Tags: r, machine-learning, word2vec, embedding, doc2vec

In the documentation of paragraph2vec only documents with less than 1000 words should be used.

However, if I train a model with a corpus that contained documents with more than 1000 words, I do not get an error message. However, some words are then used as doc_id or as line name. Is there a way to perform the calculation with more than 1000 words per document? Where does this limitation come from?

```
model <- paragraph2vec(x = data, type = "PV-DBOW", dim = 300, iter = 1)
embedding <- as.matrix(model)
embedding
```

[image]

Comment: Limitation is coming from here https://github.com/bnosac/doc2vec/blob/master/src/doc2vec/common_define.h#L14

Comment: Readme at https://github.com/bnosac/doc2vec shows how to limit your text to 1000 words

Comment: If you have texts with more than 1000 words it considers word 1001 as the document identifier

Comment: Thanks @user13818093 my question is more whether there is a theoretical reason for this limit.

Comment: No, there is no theoretical hard limit but it neither makes sense to provide an infinite amount of text